# Какие типы фйалов открывают браузеры?

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, webbrowser, microsoft-edge

Привет!

Как/где можно получить полный список типов(расширение или MIME тип) файлов, которые могут быть открыты в Firefox, Chrome, IE и Edge?

Comment: Сделай дамп реестра, выгрузи все что хоть как-то связано с браузером, а там и типы найдешь

Comment: Вряд ли это даст полный список. Браузер открывает текстовый файл, но он не является программой для просмотра текстового файла